# Cron expression for the scheduler

Tags: cron, scheduler

I have to create a scheduler which have to run for 2 days(Thursday and friday) of every week from 9am of 1st till 11.59pm of 2nd day. For that I need to provide a cron expression.

```
0-0 0-0 9-23 ? * THU,FRI *
```

I am not getting how to create the cron for 39 hours between the days. It have to run every seconds between 9am of thursday and 11.59pm of friday in every week.

Comment: Would you mind creating two separate cron jobs? One for each day

Comment: Sometimes we think of things in a complex manner when there is a very simple solution. Good one @tomslabbaert

Comment: Is your intent to have cron run the job every second between the indicated times? If so, I don't think this is possible because, as stated in `man -s5 crontab`, "cron(8) examines cron entries every minute."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a valid single cron syntax exists for your needs.
Besides, as already remarked by other users in Cron you can't go under 1 minute frequency.

That said, you may create offsets putting a "sleep 1,2,3(...)" inside script code (kinda crazy). In that way, even if executed each minute, only one script really gets executed, while others are waiting for their exact second to kick in. 
I would never do this, but as a last resort...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can hack this. But you will not be assured you will get a perfect execution. The idea is to write a script that executes a command every second for 1 minute. We choose one minute as this is the smallest resolution that cron can handle. Hence, if you have system-downtime, the cron will reboot the program the first chance it gets.

**The script:** `cron_per_second`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {0..59}; do
    "$@" &
    sleep 1
done
wait
```

This executes a command with corresponding arguments 60 times. Each command is executed in the background to avoid latency due to the execution time of the command. We sleep 1 second before executing the next command. You can see how it works by just doing:

```
$ ./cron_per_second date -Ins
```

**The crontab:**

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |   .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |   |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |   |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |   |  |  |
# *  *   *  *  *   command to be executed
  * 9-23 *  *  4   /path/to/cron_per_second command arg1 arg2 arg3
  * *    *  *  5   /path/to/cron_per_second command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The first entry runs every minute Thursdays from 9 till midnight. The second entry runs every minute on Friday.

**Warning:** It is not necessarily said between two consequitive cronjobs there is no overlap. It might be, if your crontab is big, that a job is executed at xx:yy:01 wile the next one is executed at xx:yy+1:00. Hence, the subsecond cronjob might run xx:yy+1:00 twice from both cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 * 9-23 ? * THU-FRI *
```

You can try this. 
Description of this expression can be follow through below link
[https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0+*+9-23+%3F+*+THU-FRI+*&locale=en](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0%20*%209-23%20%3F%20*%20THU-FRI%20*&locale=en)

Also there is an online utility to generate cron expression, you may find it useful.
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html